# Store lines of text as a linked list then reverse their order in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, linked-list

I've been set an assignment to store lines of text up to a full stop in a linked list and reverse their order, without printing the full stop.

My code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
   char line[50];
   struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
   //intialise stuff
   char l[50];
   int i;
   struct node *head = NULL, *newNode, *current;
   head = (struct node *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
   char c;

   //read in list reversed
   printf("Enter some lines followed by '.':\n");
   while(c!='.'){
      i=0;
      do {
         c = getchar();
         if (c != '.') {
            l[i]=c;
            i++;
         }
         else
            {break;}
         } while (c!='\n');

      newNode = (struct node *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
      for (i=0;i<strlen(l);i++)
         newNode->line[i] = l[i];
      newNode->next=head;
      head = newNode;
   }



   //print reversed list
   current = head;
   while (current != NULL) {
        for (i=0;i<strlen(current->line);i++)
        printf("%c", current->line[i]);
        current = current->next;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

this code works for inputs such as:

```
hello

there

world.
```

But when I input

```
1234

4321

7777.
```

the output has strange squares with

```
  00

  01
```

over the first number, and if I input:

```
ricky

is

cool.
```

the output is:

```
cooly

is

ky

ricky
```

could anyone help me with what part of my code is causing this?

Comment: Why don't you use standard lib functions like `fgets` and `strcpy`? Your string `l` isn't null-terminated. It is also prone to buffer overflow. Another error is that you don't need to allocate memory for the head at the beginning - an empty list is one that has `head == NULL`. For completeness, you should free the allocated memory at the end.

Comment: @MOehm I was told to use getchar() for the assignment, thanks for the help though

Comment: Okay, I understand. (Using `getchar` isn't wrong, just a bit more complicated, which is probably part of the exercise.) To solve your problem, delete the first `calloc`, the one before the loop. After your `while`, add a terminating null character: `l[i] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 0):

Close the strings with '\0' otherwise strlen and pals will not be able to figure out actual size. New lines '\n' are stored within strings but head has an additional '.' to deal with.

```
const uint SZ = 50;
struct node { struct node * next; char line[SZ]; };
struct node * wnod, * head = 0;
uint idx;
char ch = '\n';
// read in list reversed
printf( "Enter some lines followed by '.':\n" );
while( '.' != ch )
{
    wnod = ( struct node * ) calloc( 1, sizeof( struct node ) );
    wnod->next = head;
    for( idx = 0; idx < SZ - 1; ++idx )
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if( ( '.' != ch ) && ( '\n' != ch ) )
        { 
                    wnod->line[idx] =   ch;
        } else {    
                    wnod->line[idx] = '\0'; idx = SZ;
        }
    }
    head = wnod;
}
// print linked list
while( head )
{
    for( idx = 0; idx < strlen( head->line ); ++idx )
    {
        printf( "%c", head->line[idx] );
    }
    printf( "|\n" );
    wnod = head; head = head->next; free( wnod );
}
```